# Should I use an object's property or the internal variable when coding inside the object?

Tags: .net, oop

I am cleaning up some code in a class that has a settable property, with a local variable holding the value.

Some parts of the code currently call externally to get the value rather than using its own property, other parts sometimes use the property itself whilst in others the local variable is used.

In this case the property is simply set by the factory method that creates an object of this class, so the property always is the same as the variable. However I am not sure that I should be assuming this is the case in the code I am writing as that makes it harder in the future to add logic behind the getter method.

Is this something where either might be right, or am I forgetting something basic in my OO principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce complexity and increase maintainability.

First thing you should do is reduce the number of places an item exist (which you seem to be doing).

Next you should use any language tricks to reduce the size of the code. For exmaple in some versions of c# you don't need to declare fields to hold values of properties.

Once you done this you can chooses either method - there is not performance optimisation that comes from one over the other. But to be consistent. That is will increase maintainability.

Personally I prefer to always use properties where I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and only add a private variable and extra get/set code if you need to later.

e.g.

```
  public int CustomerID { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use properties, except of fields that I mark them as `readonly` which means they get their constant value only through object initialization/constructor.

Properties to me are more easy to maintain if any requirements of your application change in the future. You just have to add code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

From an OO standpoint, I think there are two types of properties.  (Note:  this applies only from inside the class.  Class users *should not* be aware of this difference.)

Some properties are really independent classes contained within the main class.  (The "main" class being the class under consideration, not necessarily the one that starts a program.)  They should be referenced only through the property, even in the main class's code.  Looking at its get and set methods should tell you the whole story of the property.  They are not integral parts of the main object but rather associated information, like public fields but safer.

The other sort *are* integral parts of the main object.  In extreme cases, they may not even have an associated field; when called, the getter might assemble a value with calculations involving many fields.  When there is a single field, internal code that reads and writes to it is apt to find the getter and setter make too many changes to it.  (The object might track a value that starts as 5.  Over time, 10 might be subtracted and 12 added.  At that point, the value should be 7.  But the getter might never want to admit to the outside world to having a value less than zero, so when the value is -5 it would return 0.)

I would decide which type of property each one is, and then go one way or the other.  Don't split the difference.  Either all references should be to the property itself or all references should be to the field or fields behind it.  (Except it may be better to reference the property directly rather than duplicate the code in the getter and setter.  I'm not real comfortable with this, though.)

By "call externally" I gather there is a normal method that returns the field's value.  This might make sense.  To be intuitive, a property has to behave as much like a public field as possible, where a regular method can make changes.  (Consider a property DistanceInFeet and a method GetDistanceInMeters()).  And it would make sense to call a Get method rather than duplicate its code.  This does mean the overall property is of the second type, an integral part of the object.

So the code you are cleaning up might be right, OO-wise--but I suspect not.